# Configure checkstyle for method chaining?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

Our project contains many statements in the method chaining fluent style:

```
    int totalCount = ((Number) em
        .createQuery("select count(up) from UserPermission up where " +
            "up.database.id = :dbId and " +
            "up.user.id <> :currentUserId ")
        .setParameter("dbId", cmd.getDatabaseId())
        .setParameter("currentUserId", currentUser.getId())
        .getSingleResult())
        .intValue();
```

I've got checkstyle mostly configured to match our existing code style, but now it's failing on these snippets, preferring instead:

```
    int totalCount = ((Number) em
        .createQuery("select count(up) from UserPermission up where " +
            "up.database.id = :dbId and " +
            "up.user.id <> :currentUserId ")
            .setParameter("dbId", cmd.getDatabaseId())
                .setParameter("currentUserId", currentUser.getId())
                    .getSingleResult())
                        .intValue();
```

Which is totally inappropriate. Is there anyway to configure checkstyle to accept the method chaining style? Is there an alternate tool I can run from maven to enforce this kind of indentation?

Comment: I suggest to add current checkstyle configuration to the question.

Comment: Also I find it quite reasonable to format it the second way. I find the first version very difficult to read.

Comment: @Martin The second way is undesired for message chaining because it seems like you always do something on the new returned object while the object in question is always the same. Imagine five more chained methods and you have lots of white space before each new method.
In the first version its clear that each new method starts at the same level. +1 for the configuration needed.

Comment: I'm voting down any answer that doesn't address checkstyle from now on.

Answer (score -2):

I never made this work in Eclipse so we barely use Format Source. In the end it is often best to extend. We tried hard and failed. It was one and half year ago. In the end we use formatting text only in Eclipse by Selecting the line or to preformat before we format by hand.

Usually the formating done by a engineer carries a certain meaning. And so automatic format will never work. Especially if you do something like

`public static void myMethod(
        int value, String value2, String value3)`

If you autoformat this it fails similar to your example.

So feel free to join the club of not using automatic formatting beside as a step before you format it the human way.

Comment: That works OK if you never join lines, which *is* a setting in Eclipse. I'm not aware of one for method chaining though.

Comment: Although this is an interesting post, it doesn't seem to be about configuring checkstyle.

Answer (score -4):

with intellij , it can be done by selecting "align when multiline" in case of "method chain calls" so i guess this property is misconfigured in the configurations.